# replace yaml field with content of file

Tags: awk, sed, yaml

I recently asked a question very similar to this one but failed to provide enough feedback for what would be a solution for this particular case. Opening this question with further information and context.

I have two files:

**File1:**

```
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition'
another_not_keyword: 'something'
```

**File2:**

```
condition 1 condition 2 condition 3
```

I would like to find all occurrences of `keyword` in **File1** and replace its content *(condition)* with the content of **File2**.

Desired output in this case:

```
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition 1 condition 2 condition 3'
another_not_keyword: 'something"
```

It's my intent to have the replacement happen in place (directly on the file itself). A solution using gawk was given, but unfortunately I can't use anything other than sed or awk.

Comment: Will there always be only one line in `file2`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes.

Answer (score 1):

`Awk` approach:

```
awk '$1=="keyword:"{ getline k < "file2"; print $1, "\047" k "\047"; next }1' file1
```

The output:

```
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition 1 condition 2 condition 3'
another_not_keyword: 'something'
```

---

As an alternative use `sed` in-place substitution:

```
$ sed -Ei "s/^(keyword: ).*/\1'$(cat file2)'/" file1
```

Comment: This provides the correct output put not directly in the file (in place). Any chance I can do changes in the file without having to use gawk?

Comment: @t988GF, have you tried `awk '<command>' file1 > tmp1 && mv tmp1 file1` ?

Comment: @t988GF, see my update

Comment: Getting -e expression #1, char 81: unknown option to `s' (on GNU sed 4.4) @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: the sed script will fail cryptically for various contents of file2, e.g. `/` or `&` or `\2` or `$` or... The awk script with getline has issues too, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline, but they're less likely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0
    next
}
$1 == "keyword:" {
    $0 = $1 OFS "\047" new "\047"
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition 1 condition 2 condition 3'
another_not_keyword: 'something'
```

Comment: Thank you Ed, this replaces the text as expect. Would there be a way to make it a bit more "portable", without requiring the .awk file? Also, is it possible to replace inline? As I mentioned in the post using gawk for inline is not possible.

Comment: Just do `awk 'NR == FNR {
    new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0;
    next
}
$1 == "keyword:" {
    $0 = $1 OFS "\047" new "\047"
}
{ print }' file2 file1`. When you say "replace inline" - do you mean modify one of the original input files? If so, which one? In any case, you'd just do `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file` - that's all that any of the "inplace" editing tools do internally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for a solution using a YAML-unaware tool. I'm giving a solution using [`yq` by Andrey Kislyuk](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) (not Mike Farah's `yq`), which is YAML-aware:

```bash
yq -Y '.keyword = input' file newdata
```

The output, given the data in the question:

```yaml
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition 1 condition 2 condition 3'
another_not_keyword: 'something'
```

You may use `-i` or `--in-place` to make an in-place edit.